# Why did Aaron apologize to Outcome #3?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

In *The Bourne Legacy (2012)*, forced to survive weather extreme and traverse rugged terrain to he arrived
at a remote cabin as punishment for missing training and going off the grid
for four days, Aaron met Outcome#3 in Alaska mountains. Outcome#3 took him
to crib, where he notices some test tubes and pills are on the desk:

> Aaron: The blood work? That's yours, isn't it? You're not a contact,
> are you? Look, I'm **sorry** to call you out like that.

Why did Aaron apologize to Outcome #3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's apologizing for "calling him out" as another chemically altered agent.

Calling someone out is a standard American English statement meaning (amongst other things) to drawing attention to someone or some aspect of someone.  Usually it refers to something that is poor behavior or something that someone is hiding.

It's all in the quote you give.  He's saying that the 'blood work' is from Outcome#3, that he's not (just) a contact and then apologizes for making that statement.